# Update from Fortran IV to Fortran 77

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I have received an consulting assignment where I will update a Fortran IV program to Fortran 77. The problem is that I never coded in Fortran. Can you give me tips on where I can learn Fortran and what is the difference between the Fortran IV and 77?

**Edit**

The program to be updated is running on a [MODCOMP 9250](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MODCOMP) (See pictures [here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/39561370@N00/238688862/)) The program was developed on the original compiler. The compiler was updated to Fortran 77 around 1990. My clients want to do some modifications to the application and want to take this opportunity to update the code to the latest compiler

Comment: Upgrading from Jurassic to Cretaceous. I strongly suggest you to refuse the assignment.

Comment: The project I'm working in has the task of managing these computers that are used in several Swedish nuclear power plant. My colleagues can program Fortran, but I've got this assignment because I am also going to teach me. They could teach me, but they are so busy.

Comment: so we are going to have a European Fukushima soon ?

Comment: I think your best chance is to hire an old Russian scientist. They are the only ones that still can deal with that stuff.

Comment: Ha ha ha, I'd take the job.  I'll even update the f77 to use MPICH/MPI and make it a killer exe.

Comment: I'd really like to know how this project turned out...

Comment: @Matt Wenham The program is now up and running with no problems. As this was my first project in this environment, everything was not perfect. But it works anyway, and will probably run many years ahead before anyone will touch the code again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems a really bizarre assignment ... is the purpose to teach that programming languages have improved over the decades?    If so, why not translate into a modern language, such as Fortran 95?

While I occasionally encounter legacy FORTRAN 77 code, it has been a very long time since I worked with true FORTRAN IV -- it is hard to remember the differences.    I think that the biggest was improved IF statements, that made it easier to write clearer code.    A list of the changes appears at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran

If you are using gfortran, the following options should compile a FORTRAN 77 program:

```
gfortran -ffixed-form  -ffixed-line-length-none  -W  -Wall -pedantic -o my_prog.exe   my_prog.for
```

Comment: The chance is, as you already probably suspect yourself, that the professor/person giving the assignment is also unaware of the differences between fIV, f77, f90/95, ... and that fIV program already contains some f77 elements, if not f90 or newer. I used to see examples like that all the time (f77 program with a MODULE inserted, for example).

Comment: Fortran 77 is the newest compiler on the platform

Answer (score 4):

The best place for checking the differences between the two is the fortran standards drafts (latest drafts are practically identical to the published standards; only they're free for download).

For example, [f77 standard](http://www.fortran.com/F77_std/rjcnf.html).

The problem however is that in the time of fIV standards were not so followed, and almost all (I can even safely say *all*) compilers included a variety of vendor extensions, of which some are surely found in your program as well. So, take a compiler manual, if you have one, as well.

The process of "updating to f77" (Gawd, I never thought I would say that - "updating to f77") would for you, be best to go in a way.
a) take a fortran short tutorial somewhere (a lot of them on the internet); just to see what fortran looks like
b) once you start recognizing program elements and structures, you can start translating it. Probability is that you will have to translate a lot of TYPE (depends) to WRITE or PRINT, modify some IF statements, modify some file input/output operations, you'll probably also encounter some COMMONs, with which you can have more or less problems, ... in any case, try, and when get stuck, post here.

How big is your assignment?

p.s. As I said in some comment above, chances are the program you're translating isn't really fIV but a mixture of fIV, f66/77, maybe even some elements of f90 - but your professor/person giving the assignment isn't aware of the difference. Unless you just copied it from an old data tape. I used to see such examples all the time.

Comment: The program is not so big, 2 KLOC. And you are right that it is lots of special commands, many call to the "database". There is an old typewriter written manual for the compiler. I may try to interpret it.

Comment: @magol - Fortran does not have *that many* keywords (f77 - maybe 30, give or take) and for that initial stage you'll mostly need to translate i/o functions (read/write/file open/close ...), and maybe some DO loops and IF statements. After that it will in my guess, compile on '77. But, I find it very hard to believe that there isn't a f90 compilant compiler for your platform. In your comment above, did you mean that there doesn't exist one or that f77 is the newest compiler you've got available at site?

Comment: The operating system (named MAX) has not been updated somewhat since around 1990, and that's when we got Fortran 77. There are no newer version to get to this platform.

Answer (score 3):

Most of Fortran IV is valid Fortran 77. If you can find a platform with g77 (the old GNU Fortran 77 compiler) installed, turn on standards-compliance-mode, and compile without warnings or errors, you are done. If the professors says that is not enough, he needs to be more specific about what he wants.

I don't know if any Fortran 95 compilers have an option that lets you check for Fortran 77 compliance.

Comment: The system has both compiler for Fortran IV and Forttran 77. But the customer wants that I update the program

Comment: it is a Standard requirement that all f2003 compilers (maybe even 2008) compile f77 code. I'm not on my work machine, but I believe f66 even is a switch at some.

Answer (score 1):

Googling "fortran 77 tutorial" throws up quite a few hits which look like reasonable introductions to the structure and syntax of Fortran 77 programs (I can't recommend anything from personal experience as I learnt it at university way back in the day) - the top hit for me looks like as good an intro as any:

http://www-teaching.physics.ox.ac.uk/Unix+Prog/hargrove/tutorial_77/

You'll probably also need to look up specific details on the compiler you'll be using (gfortran seems to the standard one for Linux these days), if only to find out the correct command line how for compiling your code.

If you're coming form the background of more modern languages then the key points to know are:

- Standard Fortran 77 is not a free-format language
- It is procedural and doesn't support object-orientation (though this is available in later revisions of the language)

However it does support the usual basic programming structures i.e. if/else, loops etc.

Hope this helps - good luck!

Comment: There is an old typewriter written manual for the compiler. I may try to interpret it. I normally program in C++ and C#, so this is strange for me. Although I have the program Basic and other easier languages. So with a little practice and reading of examples and manuals I'll probably get some understanding.